Variable not being echoed correctly, inserting itself into another variable
I'm very new to bash and I have an assignment where I must create a script which reads an url and extract the http code, the encoding used and the word count. Everything works perfectly except the word count : I tested the command and it works when isolated, but when I store it in a variable and add it at the end of my echo it seems to insert itself in place of "http"?? and what's weirder is that for one URL it works and displays at the end. I'm really lost I've been trying to understand what's wrong and I'm sure the answer is silly and simple but I can't seem to get why. Could someone please explain to me what I did wrong ?
Here's my code, I have a variable "count" which stores the result of the wc command. When I try it isolated with one url it works and shows me the number.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
echo "Le script demande un argument"
exit 1
fi

urls=$1

if ! [[ $urls =~ ".txt"$ ]]
then
echo "Ce n'est pas un format valide"
exit 2
fi

i=1
while read -r line
do
code=$(curl -ILs "$line" | grep "HTTP/" | cut -d' ' -f2)
charset=$(curl -ILs "$line" | grep -i "Content-Type:" | cut -d" " -f3 | cut -d"=" -f2)
if [ -z "$charset" ]
then
charset="null"
fi
count=$(lynx "$line" -dump -nolist | wc -w)
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n' "$line" "$code" "$charset" "$count"
i=$((i + 1))
done < "$urls"

Here's what I get :
 1       6401 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot     200     UTF-8
 2       1171 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_de_cuisine          200     UTF-8
 3       1730 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_d%27indexation      200     UTF-8
 4       2278 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bot_informatique          200     UTF-8
 5       1157 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(robot)     200     UTF-8
 6       https://roboty.magistry.fr      200     null    35 
 7       1618 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)          200     UTF-8
 8       4525 ://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/robot    200     UTF-8
 9       1048 ://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocole_d%27exclusion_des_robots        200     UTF-8
 10      12985 //fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotique         200     UTF-8

And I expected the numbers that got inserted in the url (like 6401) to be at the end, just like in line 6.
Here are the bash -x logs :
+ urls=./urls/fr.txt
+ [[ ./urls/fr.txt =~ \.txt$ ]]
+ i=1
+ read -r line
++ curl -ILs https://roboty.magistry.fr
++ grep HTTP/
++ cut '-d ' -f2
+ code=200
++ curl -ILs https://roboty.magistry.fr
++ grep -i Content-Type:
++ cut '-d ' -f3
++ cut -d= -f2
+ charset=
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ charset=null
++ lynx https://roboty.magistry.fr -dump -nolist
++ wc -w
+ count=35
+ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n' https://roboty.magistry.fr 200 null 35
https://roboty.magistry.fr      200     null    35
+ i=2
+ read -r line
++ curl -ILs 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)'
++ grep HTTP/
++ cut '-d ' -f2
+ code=200
++ curl -ILs 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)'
++ grep -i Content-Type:
++ cut '-d ' -f3
++ cut -d= -f2
+ charset=$'UTF-8\r'
+ '[' -z $'UTF-8\r' ']'
++ lynx 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)' -dump -nolist
++ wc -w
+ count=1618
+ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n' 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)' 200 $'UTF-8\r' 1618
https://1618ikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_(Léonard_de_Vinci)  200     UTF-8
+ i=3
+ read -r line

I suppose it's because of the \r at the end of "UTF-8" ?
Thanks a lot in advance if you could help me

Check your script with shellcheck.

Thank you, I just did but it doesn't really help, I applied the fixes but it's still the same output...

This pretty much always means you've got control characters like DOS newlines. Use bash -x yourscript, or add the line set -x

Do not post images of text (or links to the same).  Instead, copy & paste the text itself into the question.

BTW, some general notes: Don't use backticks for command substitutions (the modern syntax, standardized since the early 90s, is $( )), and don't use echo -e -- printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n' "$line" "$code" "$charset" "$count" works across more shells and more configurations (even bash can be configured to make echo -e print -e on output), and doesn't risk interpreting content within your line's literal data as control sequences.

And following up on @CharlesDuffy, the HTTP protocol uses CRLF (DOS-style) line terminators, so it's eminently plausible that you're getting one or more of those into your output.

nod. We'll be able to say definitively after the question has been edited to have an xtrace transcript (the debug logs bash -x yourscript prints). You'll probably want to shorten the input file to have only one url that works right and one that doesn't when generating that log, to keep it reasonably sized.

(btw, if you applied the fixes shellcheck suggested to your real code, [edit] to apply them to the code in the question too so we don't get distracted by problems that aren't directly part of the cause of the issue you're here to ask about).

Thanks a lot for all your responses ! I added/edited everything you told me. I suppose it's indeed because of the /r we can see after the UTF-8 ?

I added a sed command for my charset variable to remove the trailing /r and it worked ! Thanks everyone.

(and yes, the \r -- aka CR -- is one of the two major differences between DOS CRLF newlines and UNIX LF newlines; the other one is that in UNIX even the last line of a file is expected to have a newline after it, whereas in DOS, newlines separate lines rather than terminating them).

You just need to clean up the new line chars and things like that, here is an updated version I quickly put together.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check if exactly one argument is provided
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Le script demande un argument"
    exit 1
fi

urls_file="$1"

# Check if the provided argument is a .txt file
if [[ "$urls_file" != *.txt ]]; then
    echo "Ce n'est pas un format valide"
    exit 2
fi

# Check if the file exists and is readable
if [ ! -r "$urls_file" ]; then
    echo "Erreur : Le fichier '$urls_file' n'existe pas ou n'est pas lisible."
    exit 3
fi

# Initialize a counter (optional if tracking line numbers)
i=1

# Process each URL in the file
while IFS= read -r url ;do
#while read -r url; do
    # Skip empty lines
    if [ -z "${url}" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Get the HTTP status code
    code=$(curl -ILs "${url}" | grep -m 1 "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
    if [ -z "$code" ]; then
        code="null"
    fi

    # Get the charset from the Content-Type header
    charset="$(curl -ILs "${url}" | grep -i "Content-Type:" | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9:\/ ]//g' | tr -d '\n\r')"
    if [ -z "$charset" ]; then
        charset="null"
    fi

    # Count words on the page content using curl and wc
    count=$(curl -s "${url}" | wc -w | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
    if [ -z "$count" ]; then
        count="null"  # Handle cases where curl fails to retrieve content
    fi
    # Print results in a tab-separated format
    echo "${url} $code $charset $count"

    # Increment the counter (optional)
    i=$((i + 1))
done < "$urls_file"

Output:
https://roboty.magistry.fr 200 text/html 166

** Quick Discussion:**
Error Checking:
The text file check should be more robust, I added in an additional check with error code 3 if it fails. In addition, you should have checks for the results, if it fails it should populate with a 'null' string or 'NA' etc. You should also skip empty lines, which I did with the 'continue'.
Variable Naming:
Also work on your variable naming, it should describe things as best as possible (eg. urls_file is a better description).
Simplify the commands:
You shouldn't need lynx to get a word count, I didn't know what you were getting a word count of so I assumed it was all of the text and not just the html words the user would see.
Debugging:
You should next time print each output after assignement to check for additional characters  like so :  echo "|||||${my_variable}|||||" does it look as expected ?
